# How to change color of default Flutter words in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter

I would like to see a color difference between default words in Flutter as apposed to user created words, like variables, function names, etc.
Is there an easy way to change the color of Flutter default code words?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like changing the theme in your IDE? What IDE are you using, VSCode, Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

No, not the theme.
If I write code, I want my code to be a different color than the default words. For instant, Text is red, Comments are green.
If I create a function, I want the name of the new function to be a different color, and any variables to be a different color. Anything I write to be a color.
Hope that explains it.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and do not post details / additions as an answer.